# Iphone while google map always receive GPS signal

Tags: iphone, google-maps, gps

I am writing an application to retrieve GPS location, when I tested on many devices I have notice that sometimes my app does not retrieve GPS signal. When this happens I switch to Google map, locate my position and come back to my app to find that it can retrieve GPS location now.

I dont know how can Google do that?

Answer (score 0):

See [this discussion](http://androidforums.com/g1-support/8868-how-get-gps-coordinates-browser.html) about GPS and high accuracy in mobile browsers

It would be also more usefull, if you had posted the code of your app.